What is the difference between global variable and object declaration within the same module
I have tried to find information on this topic without luck. What is the difference between these two declarations.
//global declaration
val eventLog = EventLog()
class EventLog() {
   fun log(event:Event) {}
}

and
//no global variable
object EventLog() {
   fun log(event:Event){}
}

The way I understand it there is no difference. As a global variable the eventLog will be instantiated once and will act as a singleton.  As an Object declaration it will again be instantiated once and act as singleton.

An object declaration creates a Singleton (as in the Singleton design pattern). A Singleton does not just mean that you only have a single instance; it means you can only have a single instance of the singleton class.
In your first snippet ("global declaration"), there is nothing stopping you from creating multiple instances of EventLog.
In the case of an event log, it may be desirable to have multiple instances; for example, you might have different logs writing to different files, or you might have different logs according to their sources. Think carefully before deciding whether a class should be a singleton or not.

Yeah that is true. You can create multiple.
